# Are triggers transaction?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have some triggers `BEFORE INSERT`, `AFTER DELETE` on a table. How do I make sure if trigger fails, then my query gets rollback?

I mean I want to be sure, either both query and trigger work or none of them doesn't work. So are triggers transaction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL transaction and trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634787/mysql-transaction-and-trigger)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can show this via a stored procedure. The concept was lifted from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19908197) from wchiquito. I believe you will find this to be a more exhaustive answer. It is just an example. Make necessary changes for you particular needs (other trigger types) etc. How one performs the mysql trigger signal firing *outside* of not using stored procedures is anyone's guess. So if you are not willing or able to do the stored procedure, **read no further**.

Note that any drops or truncates are left in for your convenience and remmed out.

### Schema

```
create database trigTranTest;   -- creates a separate database for testing
use trigTranTest;   -- use that database

-- drop table tableA;
create table tableA
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    something varchar(100) not null,
    age int not null,    -- do not accept unlucky 13
    myDT datetime not null 
);

-- drop table tableB;
create table tableB
(   -- simply to demonstrate multiple tables in a transaction and that they are honored as a group (ie: Transaction)
    -- all or nothing basically
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    something varchar(100) not null,
    myDT datetime not null 
);

-- drop table auditInfoNotInTrans;
create table auditInfoNotInTrans
(   -- a boring table outside of Transaction to show an attempt was made
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    debugInfo varchar(100) not null,
    myDT datetime not null 
);
```

### Trigger

```
-- POINT A
drop trigger if exists tableA_BeforeIns;
DELIMITER $$
create trigger tableA_BeforeIns before insert on tableA
for each row
begin
    if new.age = 13 then
        -- disallow unlucky age=13 for inserts. Wait another year.
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = "tableA_BeforeIns bombed due to age=13";
    end if;
end$$
DELIMITER ;
-- POINT B
```

A quick note on the trigger: if you attempt to insert age=13, the signal will be set. This will set in motion the ultimate `ROLLBACK` of the Transaction.

Please note that DELIMITERS are important. To modify the above, highlight ALL text between your `POINT A` and `POINT B` and execute it. That block will perform the drop and recreation using the sort of pain in the rear need of DELIMITERs. Without the DELIMITER, **Error 1064** is imminent. Translation: it won't work. What won't work? The part of creating the trigger to begin with.

### Stored Procedure

```
-- POINT A
drop procedure if exists insertChunk;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insertChunk(pSomething varchar(100), pAge  int)
    -- takes two parameters, a string for a thing, and an age 
BEGIN
    -- idea lifted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19908197 by user wchiquito
    -- so spread the appreciation there
    DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;

    -- the following happens outside of the Transaction
    insert auditInfoNotInTrans(debugInfo,myDT) values(pSomething,now());

    -- now our Transaction part begins
    START TRANSACTION;
    insert tableA(something,age,myDT) values (pSomething,pAge,now());   -- pAge being unlucky 13 fails via the Trigger
    IF `_rollback` THEN
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        insert tableB(something,myDT) values (pSomething,now());
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
-- POINT B
```

A quick note here: once the `START TRANSACTION` has occured, we will get to `COMMIT` unless our trigger signals a SQLSTATE, thus causing a `ROLLBACK`.

As mentioned before, highlight and execute all the code inside of `POINT A` and `POINT B` to make edits to the above. This time for stored procs, but similar to the `create trigger` before.

Meaning, similar to trigger modifications with the safe wrappings of a DELIMITER block. Otherwise, Error 1064 is imminent, and the stored proc will not be created.

### Test

Note, the following remmed out truncates are left here for your convenience during Test.

```
-- truncate tableA;

-- truncate tableB;

-- truncate auditInfoNotInTrans;
call insertChunk('frog',1);
call insertChunk('lizard',13);  -- force a Trigger failure with the unlucky 13
call insertChunk('snake',2);
```

### Results

```
select * from auditInfoNotInTrans;
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| id | debugInfo | myDT                |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 | frog      | 2016-06-10 15:09:02 |
|  2 | lizard    | 2016-06-10 15:09:06 |
|  3 | snake     | 2016-06-10 15:09:08 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+

select * from tableA;
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+
| id | something | age | myDT                |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+
|  1 | frog      |   1 | 2016-06-10 15:09:02 |
|  2 | snake     |   2 | 2016-06-10 15:09:08 |
+----+-----------+-----+---------------------+

select * from tableB;
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| id | something | myDT                |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 | frog      | 2016-06-10 15:09:02 |
|  2 | snake     | 2016-06-10 15:09:08 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
```

Results are as expected honoring transaction handling and not allowing inserts with age=13. Sure, it is arbitrary, but we have to test it somehow.

### Call via Mysql Workbench

One last visual. Run an insert directly from Mysql Workbench with age=13

```
insert tableA(something,age,myDT) values ('turtle',13,now());
```

> Error Code: 1644. tableA_BeforeIns bombed due to age=13   0.000 sec

### Cleanup

```
drop database trigTranTest;
```

The test database has been dropped and is gone.

Comment: So that means we can't call procedure who have a transaction from a trigger?

Answer (score 5):

From the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html):

For transactional tables, failure of a statement should cause rollback of all changes performed by the statement. Failure of a trigger causes the statement to fail, so trigger failure also causes rollback.

Comment: *"For transactional tables"* ... What do you mean exactly? How can I understand whether my table is transactional or not?

Comment: A transactional table is a table that support transactions. A statement is executed within a transaction when the effect of this statement can be committed or rollbacked.

Comment: @MartinAJ  For MySQL, it depends on the engine of your table. For example, InnoDB is transactional, while MyISAM is not.